# First condition of an if-block is getting skipped

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, if-statement, find

I'm writing code with Python 2.7 that checks if a character is present in a input string but Python keeps skipping part of my if-statement.

Each time I run the code and enter a `guess` character value, the execution goes straight to the `else` statement and never executes the `if(guess in PuzzleSetter) == True` block at all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    PuzzleSetter = " "
List = []
def setPuzzle():
    PuzzleSetter = raw_input("Puzzle setter set your word: ")
    PuzzleSetter = PuzzleSetter.replace(" ", "")
    print("Guessing player try guessing: "+PuzzleSetter.upper())
    time.sleep(5)
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")
    List = [' __ ']*len(PuzzleSetter)
    print("\n")
    print(List)

    while(True):
        guess = raw_input("\nGuessing player make your guess: ")
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("You are meant to enter a single letter")
            continue
        else:
            guess = guess.upper()
            print(guess)
            if(guess in PuzzleSetter) == True:
                finder = PuzzleSetter.find(guess)
                print(PuzzleSetter+" contains "+str(PuzzleSetter.count(guess))+" "+guess+"'s")
                for count in range(PuzzleSetter.count(guess)):
                    List[finder] = guess.upper()
                    finder = PuzzleSetter.find(guess, finder+1)
                print(List)
                if List.count("__") == 0:
                    print("Guessing player wins!")
                    break
            else:
                HangerMan()
                enter += 1
                if enter == 7:
                    print("Guessing player lost!")
                    print("\nPlayer two becomes the puzzle setter")
                    setPuzzle()
```

Comment: what is PuzzleSetter?

Comment: How is `PuzzleSetter` defined? The only reason I see that it would be skipped is basically if `guess` is not in `PuzzleSetter`. If PuzzleSetter (which doesn't seem to be a list) cannot process the `in` check, this line will always evaluate to `False` and jump to the `else` block. Highly suggest you post `PuzzleSetter`'s definition as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: A quick note on style: `== True` is redundant and best left out.

Comment: If `PuzzleSetter` contains only lower case letters, the `guess` which has been converted to upper case will never be found in it.

Comment: i just edited the code guys to show how PuzzleSetter is defined, please guys check out and help please

Comment: You're also going to find a problem with `List` since it doesn't contain the same number of characters as `PuzzleSetter`.  I'll leave you to figure that one out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, you're leaving `PuzzleSetter` as input and not converting it to upper case like you are `guess`.  If it contains any lower case letters they will never be found.  Try this:

```
PuzzleSetter = raw_input("Puzzle setter set your word: ")
PuzzleSetter = PuzzleSetter.replace(" ", "")
PuzzleSetter = PuzzleSetter.upper()
print("Guessing player try guessing: "+PuzzleSetter)
```